# How to insert two or more rows into table using mysqli_multi_query() with out insertion errors?

Tags: php, mysqli, mysqli-multi-query

I need to insert rows to more than one table and the number of rows that I need to insert is not fixed .
I am using mysqli_multi_query() to do all my insert queries in  a single step.

I need to execute all my queries successfully or else if one of the queries failed revert to original table .

How can I do this ?

My query is

```
insert into `_survey_user_map` (`user`,`survey`) values('anu','1')
```

on duplicate key update `survey`='1';
delete from `_survey_db` where `user`='anu';

Comment: Can you share the relevant code you currently have?

Answer (score 2):

Use transactions.

```
MySQLi::begin_transaction();

// Make your SQL queries here...

if (NO ERROR OCCURRED) {
    MySQLi::commit();
} else {
    MySQLi::rollback();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of running multiple queries that `INSERT`s one row each, compose a single `INSERT` query that inserts all the rows. It will fail and doesn't insert anything if at least one of the rows cannot be inserted.

```
INSERT INTO tbl_name (a,b,c) VALUES(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9);
```